Why do conditional object types with a template literal key match any object regardless of its keys?
I want to make a Typescript utility type that extracts certain subtypes from a complex union of objects if they contain keys that match a template. For simplicity let's say I want to match object types that contain any key that starts with an underscore.
However, conditional types with a key with a template literal seem to always match any object, regardless of whether a matching key exists. Here's a simplified example:
// ❌ Conditional type on object with template literal key not working as expected
type HasTemplateProperty<T> = T extends { [key: `_${string}`]: string } ? true : false

type testA1 = HasTemplateProperty<{ _test: string }> // ✅ true, as expected
type testA2 = HasTemplateProperty<{ test: string }> // ❌ true, not expected
type testA3 = HasTemplateProperty<{}> // ❌ true, not expected
type testA4 = HasTemplateProperty<number> // ✅ false, as expected

// ✅ Conditional type on object with string literal key is working as expected
type HasLiteralProperty<T> = T extends { _test: string } ? true : false

type testB1 = HasLiteralProperty<{ _test: string }> // ✅ true, as expected
type testB2 = HasLiteralProperty<{ test: string }> // ✅ false, as expected
type testB3 = HasLiteralProperty<{}> // ✅ false, as expected
type testB4 = HasLiteralProperty<number> // ✅ false, as expected

// ✅ Conditional type template literal on its own is working as expected
type MatchesTemplate<T> = T extends `_${string}` ? true : false

type testC1 = MatchesTemplate<'_test'> // ✅ true, as expected
type testC2 = MatchesTemplate<'test'> // ✅ false, as expected
type testC3 = MatchesTemplate<'test_'> // ✅ false, as expected
type testC4 = MatchesTemplate<number> // ✅ false, as expected

Demo on Typescript Playground
I've seen some other discussions of unexpected behaviours in Typescript template literals and object keys, but I can't find anything about this specific behaviour. I also found this open issue on Typescript's GitHub which talks about computed property key names being unexpectedly widened to string, which may be relevant, but doesn't explain "testA3" where an object with no properties is considered a match.
Why is Typescript doing this? I can't see any way to get the expected behaviour of a Typescript utility type that matches objects containing keys that match a template like { _anything: '...', anythingElse: 123 } but not objects that don't contain such keys like { anything: '...', anythingElse: 123 } (I don't think mapped properties would work in my case because I want to get the match at the level of the object not at the level of individual properties).

So the existing answer by @AlexanderNenashev answers the "why" by mentioning index signatures. Does that explain it enough for you or do you need more information in there?

Yes it does, accepted

What do you describe in the conditional type is an index signature. So it COULD contain property of key _${string} or COULDN'T. That's why {} gives true. Since {test: string} satisfies {} structurally it also gives true:
type Check = { test: string } extends {} ? true : false; // true

This is because { test: string } could be used as {} in TS.
To make your conditional type work you could check that the both actual property keys and values satisfy your conditions:
Playground
type HasTemplateProperty<T> = keyof T extends `_${string}` ? T[keyof T] extends string ? true : false : false;

type testA1 = HasTemplateProperty<{ _test: string }> // ✅ true, as expected
type testA2 = HasTemplateProperty<{ test: string }> // ✅ false, as expected

UPDATE
According the OP it's needed to have at least 1 property with _${string} key. So we could use a mapped type to filter the _${string} keys and check whether they provide string property value:
Playground
type HasTemplateProperty<T> = 
    string extends T[keyof {[K in keyof T as K extends `_${string}`? K : never]: unknown}] ? true : false

type testA1 = HasTemplateProperty<{ _test: string }> // ✅ true, as expected
type testA2 = HasTemplateProperty<{ test: false, _test: string }> // ✅ true, as expected
type testA3 = HasTemplateProperty<{ test: false }> // ✅ false, as expected
type testA4 = HasTemplateProperty<{  }> // ✅ false, as expected
type testA5 = HasTemplateProperty<{ _test: number }> // ✅ false, as expected


It's not an indexed access type, it's an index signature.

Very useful, thanks. One note on your proposed alternative is that it checks if every key matches the template, so gives false for { _test: string, test: string }. I wonder if it's possible to test if any (but at least one) key matches the template.

@user56reinstatemonica8 i've optimized the code by removing redundant checks

The answer of Alexander works, but if you want to exclude empty objects you can do this:
type HasTemplateProperty<T> = keyof T extends infer K
  ? K extends string
    ? K extends `_${string}`
      ? true
      : false
    : false
  : false;

type testA3 = HasTemplateProperty<{}>; // => never

Typescript Playground
If you want never to be false just add another check:
type HasTemplateProperty<T> = keyof T extends never
  ? false
  : keyof T extends infer K
  ? K extends string
    ? K extends `_${string}`
      ? true
      : false
    : false
  : false;


This doesn't quite seem like it should be a separate answer from the other one. Also note that this doesn't attempt to explain why it's happening, as the question title says.

Great, thanks. I created a Typescript Playground demo with both answers but the URL is too long for a comment so I'll add it to yours as an edit. Do you know why your "A3" comes through as never not false?

@jcalz It was never intended to be an answer. It was intended to extend the answer of @Alexander Nenashev.
@user56reinstatemonica8
It's because keyof {} is never.

@user56reinstatemonica8 In your playground you say this: "never, probably close enough?"
So I edited my answer so that it's always true or false. Even if now you just want to know why.

If it was never intended to be an answer then I guess you should delete it. This is an answer post and if you wanted to edit the existing answer you could do so directly. Good luck!

@jcalz I will leave it, as there is no way to format code in a comment. This is the reason I wrote it as an answer. Thanks!
